# Нужно сделать с помощью Jquery, что бы при нажатии на первую ячейку любой строки, передавался индекс строки в которой находиться эта ячейка

Tags: jquery

Имеется html таблица. Нужно сделать с помощью Jquery, что бы при нажатии на первую ячейку любой строки, передавался индекс строки в которой находиться эта ячейка.

Таблица html:

```
<table id="mytable" border="1"> 
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Код таблицы можно хотя бы?

Comment: <table id="mytable" border="1">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </table>

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td:first-child').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).parent().index());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[index();](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

При клике на любую ячейку строки:

```js
$('td').click(function(){
       
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
      index = tr.index();
  console.log(index);
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable" border="1"> 
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
  </tr> 
</table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

Если только на первую, то `td` заменить на `td:first-child` или `td:first-of-type`:

```js
$('td:first-of-type').click(function(){
       
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
      index = tr.index();
  console.log(index);
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable" border="1"> 
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
  </tr> 
</table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо, за развернутый и ясный ответ.